# Problem applying rig modifier

Tags: rigging

I'm a Blender newbie, and I'm taking a course on Udemy. I've been following along with the instructor, and when he applies the rig modifier his mesh stays where he posted it. But when I apply it, my mesh reverts to the a-pose. What am I doing wrong?

Before applying the modifier...

[image]
After applying the modifier...
[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but move the *Armature* modifier to the top and then apply it. The modifier stack works from the top down. If you apply a modifier below the top, you may get unexpected results. For example, if you have a *MultiRes* + a *ShrinkWrap* modifier and you apply the *ShrinkWrap* modifier, the result will be stored in the *MultiRes* modifier. Maybe that happens here too.

Comment: Thanks Blunder, that solved my problem!